# How can I escape variable for use with sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a variable `$salts` equal

```
define('AUTH_KEY', 'sBXb~#HPv(X>|2o2&C K&9@l+0.$M,(7-0sW.lpziIZ_EBbHIu3^S}OM-^n,)L S'); define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY', 'RX=tc=pj)y0he{FOqZp/:W{5{@[tnxUv3W_hZ+g4gL)]p!xH-.qb6]O$VHc5V@}1'); define('LOGGED_IN_KEY', '0cUHd}{d)g0X~%Qwy8wKc)cxxXFp2/wCcS=/-sH3z84jz47cV#9|%)1-uTtey(s1'); define('NONCE_KEY', 'J|_J>;_xvHA_UQ^5WDpnpq%,vy{WgNBc{K(SSqwFlwhZCCm>Db^cnBy%9X_q[<^E'); define('AUTH_SALT', '?S15/b~oVY&|ZZp]W<B%uF$<C6c%lIe_!nrVmmPWO`[37C45w9Oju!+xrL~zLnlM'); define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'iX-i>DWhT-0[E1H,[Qqmx;w}$N{B,QAF$W^m9]!1!|_y58aYnHAcXL)l~L|}W39W'); define('LOGGED_IN_SALT', 'qN!?,ORKqNBv@Mf8hb]#VLVYY>+=w*M]|=x^!)>wEl%[]R+(jD{VKOSQueiB8eo('); define('NONCE_SALT', '>,i@yn,CIb<vKOR(2[]*x)SBZzy[T]cq%|[}LBFALEPULwEVa*%C;?b$CZIS-#;*');
```

I am trying to execute command

```
cat -n wp-config.php | sed '45,52d' | sed "45i ${salts}"
```

and get error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 102: extra characters after command
```

How can I escape `$salts` variable for sed?

Comment: is your sed **Gnu** ?

Comment: Oh, forget it, I thought you could use `R` gnu extension, but you have stdin already, the `cat -n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use awk so you don't spend the rest of your life figuring out which characters you need to escape in which contexts using sed - it's an unsolvable problem and the solutions' trivial in awk and you don't need the cat and multiple pipes either:

```
awk -v salts="$salts" '
   NR==45 { $0 = salts }
   (NR < 46) || (NR > 52) { print NR, $0 }
' wp-config.php
```

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else just use awk.

Comment: Thanks for the script, actually I found it's quite easy to escape with echo $salts | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g', anyway I need to find time to learn awk :)

Comment: Those aren't the only characters you need to escape for sed though.

Comment: +1 for using awk.  I thought for quite a while that awk was a 'dead' language for most people.  I see it come up quite often on SO and related sites though.  Very useful to know, Arius2038.  The effort may pay off greatly for you down the road if you learn it.

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
cat -n wp-config.php | sed  '45,52d' | sed "45i $(echo $salts | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')"
```

Characters in `$salts` that have special meaning to `sed` need to be escaped first.

You can escape variable by:

```
echo $VARNAME | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g'
```

Comment: That will behave differently on different shells/OSs, and fail in highly cryptic ways for variables containing white space and/or globbing characters and/or starting with "-", and many other situations. Just don't do this as it's absolutely the wrong approach even if it does seem to "work" for some specific value of some specific variable.